# RewriteRule not working, but others are?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's my current .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^feature/$         /items/feature [L]
RewriteRule    ^feature$          /items/feature [L]
RewriteRule    ^top_sellers/$        /items/top_sellers [L]
RewriteRule    ^top_sellers$         /items/top_sellers [L]
RewriteRule    ^support/$         /contacts [L]
RewriteRule    ^support$          /contacts [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

All of the rewrite rules are working except for these:

```
RewriteRule    ^support/$         /contacts [L]
RewriteRule    ^support$          /contacts [L]
```

I don't understand why `mysite.com/support` would be showing a 404 page when all the other redirects are working properly.  Also, when I go to `mysite.com/contacts`, there isn't a 404 error - it loads the page correctly.

Is there any reason that a redirect with `support` in the URL wouldn't work for some odd reason on a cPanel server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rules can be consolidated quite a bit but also tell Apache to make sure it's not a **real** file or directory before processing the rule. Try these rules.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes -Multiviews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(feature|top_sellers)/?$ /items/$1 [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^support/?$ /contacts [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of these 2 rules, you can use this single rule

```
RewriteRule ^support/?$ /contacts [NC,L]
```

A slash at the end of the url is optional in this pattern. and a url ending with or without slash (/) will be accepted.

Comment: In addition, the first four rules can be combined: `RewriteRule ^(feature|top_sellers)/?$ /items/$1 [NC,L] `